# Remapping keyboard shortcuts (copy, paste etc) to Alt key instead of Ctrl

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, xmonad

Interestingly, it turns out this is almost impossible to do. Remapping <kbd>ALT</kbd> key to behave as another <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is not a solution because you lose the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key functionalities (some of which are essential, like <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>).

So how can I get a behavior similar to OSX where <kbd>CMD</kbd> key is used for keyboard shortcuts (but also for switching between windows with <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>)?

I know I can assign <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between windows after I remap <kbd>ALT</kbd> key as a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key. But then I lose the real <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> functionality in some applications, which are also essential like switching between tabs. Basically my <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys would become the same key and it will be impossible to have two different set of shortcuts for these two modifier keys.

A good solution for me would probably be a way to catch <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, etc. at the window management level and send instead a <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> etc. to the focused window. On Windows this was possible via AutoHotKey.

On Linux, I heard about an application called AutoKey but unlike AutoHotKey you have to use a GUI to set the shortcuts. Since I will be writing almost all combinations of Alt manually, I don't want a GUI application do to this. I should be able to configure it by writing a text file.

Is it possible to achieve this either with Gnome or Xmonad?

Comment: It is possible via XMonad, since you can basically hardcode/customize each and every keybinding. (You might get a good answer on http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ too)

Comment: Xmonad's keyboard shortcuts are highly customizable but the customizations are about window management. What I'm trying to do is to "send a fake keypress to the focused window". Ideally I want to be able to do this at a lower level so that it works with any window manager. Thanks for the suggestions though, I will ask there too.